# on Fedora 15, start Lift app on Fedora getting org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException

Tags: exception, lift, fedora, h2

On Fedora 15, after doing mvn jetty:run, I am getting the following excetion when it's trying to initialize the MetaMapper for User

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Exception opening port "H2 TCP Server (tcp://
192.168.1.105:33463)" (port may be in use), cause: "timeout" [90061-138]
(full stack trace is pasted last in the mail)
```

The following is how I generated the project

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=net.liftweb \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=lift-archetype-basic_2.8.1 \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.3 \
-DarchetypeRepository=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \
-DremoteRepositories=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \
-DgroupId=com.mytest \
-DartifactId=helloworld \
-Dversion=2.0
```

I tried replacing OpenJDK with Sun JDK, still doesn't work. Anything wrong with H2? Do I need to reinstall H2? Or is it a Lift issue?

If I kill the run and restart another one, I will get the same exception, but just different tcp port, for example

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Exception opening port "H2 TCP Server
(tcp://208.68.143.50:55325)" (port may be in use), cause: "timeout" [90061-138]
```

Comment: Could you try with a more recent version of H2? According to the error code, you are using version 1.2.138 (2010-06-27), and the error message has been improved in a recent version (I believe version 1.3.156).

Comment: the current version seems to get installed by maven2, as it's one of the dependencies of the lift app. if I install a new version, will maven2 still work with it?

Comment: Downloading: http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/com/h2database/h2/1.3.156/h2-1.3.156.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.156' in repository scala-tools.releases (http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.3.156/h2-1.3.156.jar

Comment: 13:30:26.505 [main] DEBUG net.liftweb.mapper.MetaMapper - Initializing MetaMapper for User
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Exception opening port "H2 TCP Server (tcp://208.68.143.50:36909)" (port may be in use), cause: "timeout" [90061-156]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)

Comment: still getting the same exception with h2 156.

Comment: So the questions are - why a different IP address were used, those IP
addresses are not on my network at all. why not using localhost?

The following is what I got from http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html

jdbc:h2:mem:db1. 
To access an in-memory database from another process or from another
computer, you need to start a TCP server in the same process as the in-
memory database was created. The other processes then need to access
the database over TCP/IP or SSL/TLS, using a database URL such as:
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:db1.

Comment: I believe it's a network config problem (let's discuss this on my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your application still runs or the ports haven't closed.
Verify using 'netstat'.

You may want to read on so_reuseaddr.

I have a server running on my computer (its Common Lisp and not H2 but this doesn't matter):

```
xxx@fp:~$ netstat -tulpen
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       68449       7559/sbcl
```

I would expect that either a process is listening on 208.68.143.50:55325. If this IP isn't your computer, then something weird is going on.
You can start your application with

```
sudo strace -f mvn ... 2>&1 test.out
```

and afterwards investigate the test.out file. The 'strace' tool allows you to log all the system calls that are issued by the program. Search listen in the file test.out.

Comment: I did netstat, nothing was running on the port. I updated the question. For the tcp ip+port combination, why it's different each time? is there a way to set it to be "constant"? and also the Ip address is for sure not on my network.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a network configuration problem. Could you check in your hosts file for strange entries? My hosts file is (Mac OS):

```
> cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

If there is nothing strange in this file, please download H2 and run `./build.sh testNetwork` (or `build.bat testNetwork` for Windows). On my system, I get:

```
Target: testNetwork
localhost:localhost/127.0.0.1
  localhost/127.0.0.1
  localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
  localhost/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1
getLocalHost:Thomas-Muellers-MacBook-Pro.local/192.168.0.105
  /192.168.0.105
byName:/192.168.0.105
ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=55489]
server accepting
client:/192.168.0.105:55489
server accepted:Socket[addr=/192.168.0.105,port=55490,localport=55489]
client:Socket[addr=/192.168.0.105,port=55489,localport=55490]
server read:123
client read:234
server closing
server done
done
Done in 1666 ms
```

Of course H2 could just use "localhost", but then certain features wouldn't work as designed.